# How may I make a long caption on a geom_boxplot appear?

Tags: r, ggplot2, markdown, caption

I have a long caption that I would like to include at the bottom of a ggplot `geom_boxplot`.

Currently the code writes a single line to the caption with lots of the intended caption missing.  How might I wrap the text in the caption?

My code is

```
p = ggplot(mpg, aes(class, hwy)) + geom_boxplot() +
  labs(title="An example title", caption = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.")
```

I have experimented with a few things but have got nowhere e.g. plot.caption in the theme of the ggplot.
Could anyone help?

Thank you.
Phil,

Comment: You can add line breaks with `\n`, i.e., `caption = 'Caption line 1\nand then line 2'`

Answer (score 8):

1. Manually add `\n` to the place where you would like to break the text to a new line (this method is not used in this solution). However, since your caption is quite long, it's hard to guess where is the best to put the `\n`, and not easy to align the resulting text, therefore I recommend the second method:
2. Use a function, such as `stringr::str_wrap()`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(stringr)

ggplot(mpg, aes(class, hwy)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  labs(
    title = "An example title",
    caption = str_wrap("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
      width = 80
    )
  )
```

[image: str_wrap_width80]

Answer (score 2):

Another option and alternative to `str_wrap` would be `ggtext::element_textbox`. A benefit of `ggtext::element_textbox` is that you don't have to set the linewidth, instead you specify the width of the textbook, e.g. in my example code below I use `unit(.8, "npc")` so that the caption textbox will have a length of 80 percent of the plot width.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)

library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)

ggplot(mpg, aes(class, hwy)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme(
    plot.caption =
      ggtext::element_textbox(
        width = unit(.8, "npc"),
        hjust = 1, vjust = 1,
        halign = 1
      )
  ) +
  labs(
    title = "An example title",
    caption = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
  )
```

[image]